# Importing large CSV file into MySQL workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, mysql-workbench

I am working on data analysis of a data set having approx. 140,000 records. I have the data set in form of **CSV file**. 
I am trying to **import the data into MySQL workbench,** but it only processes(adds) the first record and gives a warning that 1265 rows were truncated.
Something like this

**"0 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column 'Location' at row 1 Records: 1  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 1  Warnings: 1
"**

My actual Query is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/PMK/SFPD_Incidents.csv' INTO TABLE incidents.incidents 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(IncidntNum, Category, Description, DayOfWeek, Date, Time, PdDistrict, Resolution, Address, X, Y, Location);
```

Now, when I run the same query for small data set having less records, then it works completely fine except the **truncate warning.**

The csv content looks like this:

```
141043385,SUSPICIOUS OCC,SUSPICIOUS OCCURRENCE,Thursday,12/11/2014,21:09,SOUTHERN,NONE,800 Block of BRYANT ST,-122.403404791479,37.775420706711,"(37.775420706711, -122.403404791479)"
141043523,NON-CRIMINAL,"AIDED CASE, MENTAL DISTURBED",Thursday,12/11/2014,19:28,SOUTHERN,NONE,800 Block of MARKET ST,-122.407633520742,37.7841893501425,"(37.7841893501425, -122.407633520742)"
141042804,LARCENY/THEFT,GRAND THEFT PICKPOCKET,Thursday,12/11/2014,15:45,TENDERLOIN,NONE,100 Block of OFARRELL ST,-122.407244087032,37.7865647607685,"(37.7865647607685, -122.407244087032)"
141042622,SUSPICIOUS OCC,SUSPICIOUS OCCURRENCE,Thursday,12/11/2014,15:00,TARAVAL,NONE,0 Block of FUENTE AV,-122.477993371794,37.7193838455847,"(37.7193838455847, -122.477993371794)"
141042622,OTHER OFFENSES,FALSE PERSONATION,Thursday,12/11/2014,15:00,TARAVAL,NONE,0 Block of FUENTE AV,-122.477993371794,37.7193838455847,"(37.7193838455847, -122.477993371794)"
```

any help or fix is much appreciated.

Comment: share your csv file's some rows

Comment: Shouldn't the strings in your csv be enclosed in " too ?
For example shouldn't this:
,100 Block of OFARRELL ST
be like this:
,"100 Block of OFARRELL ST"
?

Comment: Well If it should be between quotes then it shouldn't allow me to process small data sets. But on the contrary the same query works for small number of records.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to verify/validate it.

I've had trouble with large CSV files too, but most of the time there was something wrong with the values.

So there might be a value there breaking your import.

Comment: still not working. I tried multiple ways but no luck.